# Management of fscanf() with a file

Tags: c, file, scanf, codeblocks

I'm just questioning myself on how can I take a single string from my file, without reading more of 2 strings

I explain it better:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 20
int main()
{
FILE *fp;
char string[MAX], string2[MAX];
fp = fopen("prova.txt", "r");
while(!feof(fp)){
 fscanf(fp, "#%s#%s", string, string2);
 printf("String 1: %s", string);
 printf("String 2: %s", string2);
}
return 0;
}
```

prova.txt

> **#prova1#prova2**

I just want to read prova1 and prova2 in string and string2, but everytime I try to read the first string with fscanf, the output of string is prova1#prova2, how can I resolve this?

Comment: The loop technique is incorrect. Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) A better loop is driven by the result  of `fscanf`. For example `while(fscanf(fp, "#%s#%s", string, string2) == 2) { ... }`.

Comment: "How can I take a single string from my file?" Read the line with `fgets` and break it with `strtok`.

Comment: The `%s` skips white space and then reads up to the next white space; only then does [`fscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) look at what's next.  You need scan sets `" # %[^#] # %[^#]"` to read up to but not including the hash.   The space between the second `#` and second `%` is optional (and a no-op) but consistent; the others are a good idea, not least because scan sets `%[…]` do not skip leading white space.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for the response, I made it works with strtok with another code ^^

Comment: Remember that `fgets` retains any final newline (if room)  and it is convenient to remove that by including it in the delimiter set for `strtok`.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for the tip, I'll add it to the code